# Unable to get value of service in @CanActivate decorator in component

Tags: service, annotations, angular, components

I am using Angular 2.0.0-beta.15. I am trying to use @CanActivate in the component. Below is the piece of code.

```
@CanActivate((next: ComponentInstruction, previous: ComponentInstruction) =>  { 
console.log('loggedIn:' + isLoggedIn(next, previous));
console.log('isExists:' + isExists(next, previous))
})export class ParentLandingComponent {}
```

Now relevant piece of code in isExists.ts is as below:

```
import {Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {appInjector} from './app-injector';
import {DataService} from '../services/data-services.service';
export const isExists = (next: ComponentInstruction, previous: ComponentInstruction) => {
let injector: Injector = appInjector(); 
let userService: UserService = injector.get(UserService);
let router: Router = injector.get(Router);
let cookieService: CookieService = injector.resolveAndInstantiate(CookieService);

    dataService.isExists().subscribe(result => {
        console.log('isExists:' + result);
        if (result) {
            console.log('result:' + result);
            cookieService.removeAll();
            router.navigate(['Login']);
            return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
     });
};
```

I have added the following in boot.ts as well.

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
  import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
  import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
  import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, Location, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
  import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
  import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
  import 'rxjs/Rx';
  import {DataService} from './services/data-services.service';
  import {StateService} from './services/current-user-state.service';
  import {appInjector} from './utils/app-injector';
  import {HttpClient} from './services/http-client.service';
   bootstrap(AppComponent, [DataService, StateService, HttpClient, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS,
provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })])
.then(appRef => {
    appInjector(appRef.injector);
});
```

When i running, I am getting value of isExists(next, previous) in @CanAnnotation as undefined instead of boolean value. Inside isExists.ts, I am getting correct value as result. But when i am passing boolean value based on value of result, I am getting undefined on annotation portion.Can anyone help me to know what could be the issue in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda in `CanActivate()` annotation has to return `boolean|Promise<boolean>`. Based on your code it's not returning anything. I am guessing you will return the value from `isExists()`. But, also `isExists()` doesn't return anything that's why it's `undefined`. I see you are trying to return `true/false` from the subscribe method. But that return is asynchronous and will not be resolved as you intended.

I suggest you convert your `Observable` to `Promise<boolean>` and return it from `isExists()`

relevant part in isExists():

```
return dataService.isExists().map(result => { // change subscribe to 'map' in order to change the return type of the observable and do the other stuff 
    console.log('isExists:' + result);
    if (result) {
        console.log('result:' + result);
        cookieService.removeAll();
        router.navigate(['Login']);
        return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
 }).toPromise();
```

@CanActivate():

```
@CanActivate((next: ComponentInstruction, previous: ComponentInstruction) =>  { 
    console.log('loggedIn:' + isLoggedIn(next, previous));
    return isExists(next, previous);
})
export class ParentLandingComponent {}
```

Comment: yes i have tried the following before:   return new Promise((resolve) => {dataService.isExists().map(result => { // change subscribe to 'map' in order to change the return type of the observable and do the other stuff 
    console.log('isExists:' + result);
    if (result) {
        console.log('result:' + result);
        cookieService.removeAll();
        router.navigate(['Login']);
        return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
 }); I have also tried what you said. I think both meant same.. Both are getting me [object Object] instead of Undefined.

Comment: Also when i try to stringify [object Object],its causing TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON. :(

Comment: @revathi You are not meant to `console.log()`, you should return the promise like `return isExists(next, previous);`, did you try that ?

Comment: @revathi you might also need to `import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'`

Comment: on annotation portion instead of using console.log() i put what i wanted- if (isLoggedIn(next, previous)) {
        if (isExists(next, previous)) {
            return true; // it comes always here only
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    } now in isExists.ts if(result) resolve(false) else resolve(true). But whatever value it resolved, it comes to same code. :( am I understanding wrong?

Comment: @revathi  yes :D, `isExists()` returns a promise, you can't pass the promise to if statement. You can pass it but it will always be true.  You should return the promise itself. like this:  `if (isLoggedIn(next, previous)) { return isExists(next, previous)}`

Comment: you are correct..thanks a lot for patiently explaining all my doubts. This helped me to learn. :)